# I have to "stab" at the upper left corner to get launcher to appear

Tags: 12.04, launcher, mouse

Running 12.04 LTS. This is extremely annoying and makes me want to try another flavor of Linux.

Yes, this little inconvenience is *that* annoying to me. Most of the time the launcher will appear nice and easy as soon as I mouse over the upper left corner, but many times, the left edge of the screen will get a little darker, but the launcher will not appear.

By seeing the edge darken, I know that the OS is acknowledging my mouse's presence in the corner. Only by "stabbing" the corner with my mouse can I get it to appear. I just want the launcher to appear as soon as I mouse over the corner.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the reveal sensitivity of the launcher.  This setting can be found by opening the System Settings app, selecting Appearance, and clicking on the Behavior tab. You can adjust the sensitivity with the slider, and also choose between the top-left corner or the entire left side as the hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/931982) in Unity.
You can permanently disable it or try changing it's reveal sensitivity.
[image]